# Ending a code with a designated value

Tags: java

How would I make it to where I wanted my code to loop if any character besides **n** or **N** was entered? So if the user inputs a, t, w, g, etc., it would return back to the beginning of the current loop. I'm usin an **if/else if** loop. (Just messing around with NetBeans).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvoiceApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // welcome the user to the program
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Invoice Total Calculator");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        // create a Scanner object named sc
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // perform invoice calculations until choice isn't equal to "y" or "Y"
        String choice = "y";
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            // get the invoice subtotal from the user
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountPercent= 0.0;
            if (subtotal >= 200)
            discountPercent = .2;
            else if (subtotal >= 100)
            discountPercent = .1;
            else
            discountPercent = 0.0;

            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // display the discount amount and total
            String message = "Discount percent: " + discountPercent + "\n"
                           + "Discount amount:  " + discountAmount + "\n"
                           + "Invoice total:    " + total + "\n";
            System.out.println(message);

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
        }
            else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: And choose one language Java or Javascript. Both are not same except first 4 letters.

Comment: So, what are you talking about Javascript or Java?

Comment: if/else is not loop.

Comment: Just java, sorry. It's the code at the bottom. Something needs to come after the else if command but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while(!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))` instead of your current `if` statement. You won't need an else section.

Comment: So how would I make it so that if any other character is used, it would return to the top of the loop saying something i.e. "Invalid. Please enter 1-100"?

Comment: Is that after this line? `double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();`

if yes, have an `if` statement which has a `continue` statement.

`if( (subtotal <1) || (subtotal >100)) {`
`System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter 1-100");`
     `continue;`
`}`